# Grep behavior on OS X with --only-matching

Tags: shell, unix, grep

When I run the following:

```
printf "1234\n1234" | grep -o '^.'
```

I get the following output on OSX 10.10 with zsh 5.0.5:

```
1
2
3
4
1
2
3
4
```

Why? I'd expect this output instead:

```
1
1
```

Can anyone reproduce this issue? I get the expected output on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Related: [Trouble with grep -o regex](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8892/trouble-with-grep-o-regex)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem seems to be that Apple has elected to have a more-than-a-decade-old version of `grep` on its latest operating system. It has bugs [including the one you point out](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=detailitem&item_id=11579). The only thing I can seriously suggest is that you use a package manager like [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) to upgrade the grep you use for day-to-day work.

```
$ grep --version
grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD
$ grep --color=never -o ^. <<< ab
a
b
$ brew install grep
==> Installing grep from homebrew/homebrew-dupes
<SNIP>
$ ggrep --version
ggrep (GNU grep) 2.21
$ ggrep --color=never -o ^. <<< ab
a
```

Answer (score 0):

I can not tell you what is wrong, but try a workaround:

```
printf "1234\n1234" | awk -vFS= '{print $1}'
1
1
```

By setting `FS` to nothing, every characters become separate fields, then print first field `$1`

If `-FS=` does not work try `-vFS=""`